# why does insert in std::unordered_set call the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, insert, unordered-set

I have an std::unordered_set of pointers. If I do

```
int main()
{
  std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<int>> set;
  set.insert(std::make_unique(3));
}
```

everything works and insert calls the move constructor (i think). However I have a different situation that is similar to the following code

```
std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<int>> set;
void add(const std::unique_ptr<int>& obj) {set.insert(obj);}

int main
{
  std::unique_ptr<int> val = std::make_unique<int>(3);
  add(std::move(val));
}
```

and this does not compile. It gives

State Error C2280 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

which means that it's trying to call the copy constructor (right?). So the question is: why insert doesn't move the object when it is inside a function? I tried also passing the pointer to the unique_ptr and even adding std::move pretty much everywhere but the copy constructor is always called

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void add(const std::unique_ptr<int>& obj)
```

It comes down to something fundamental: you cannot move a constant object, by definition. "Move" basically means ripping the guts out of the moved-from object, and shoving all the guts into the new, moved-to object (in the most efficient manner possible, with the precision of a surgeon). And you can't do it if the moved-from object is `const`. It's untouchable. It must remain in its original, pristine condition.

You should be able to do that if the parameter is an rvalue reference:

```
void add(std::unique_ptr<int>&& obj) {set.insert(std::move(obj));}
```

Comment: *"you cannot move a constant object, by definition"*. You might do "funny" stuff with `void foo (const MyObject&&);`.

Comment: That's not going to work, either. Feel free to try that, yourself. There's a way to do it, but it will require much more work, and the side effects must be fully understood.

Comment: Good answer. It is also possible to just use `add(std::unique_ptr<int> obj)` and move from  value type argument, directly, since unique_ptr is really small.

Comment: ohh you're right I'm so stupid . I'll try to change everything using an rvalue. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

std::unique_ptr by definition does not have a copy constructor. It does have a move constructor. But your unique pointer here is a const, so the move constructor cannot be called